# I'm receiving the error 'except MySQLdb.error, e' Syntax Error - invalid syntax when trying to write my scrapy spider to mysql,

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

Here is my pipelines.py and I'm receiving an error on line 18.

```
import sys;sys.path.append("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='test', passwd='password', db='c1024403', host='ephesus.cs.cf.ac.uk', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (test1, test2) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (item['Country'], item['Qualification']))
            self.conn.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print 'Error %d: %s' % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            sys.exit(1)

        return item
```

Heres the error -

```
File "project\pipelines.py", line 18
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've installed mysql-python and visual c++ 2008 express, I don't understand what the error means as I can't find anything about it anywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 7):

You are running your code with `Python 3.x`, but your code scheme for `try.. except` section is for `Python 2.X`.

If you want to run your code with `Python 3.x`, then change this line:

```
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
```

To:

```
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
```

And if you want this section of code works with `Python 2.x` and also `Python 3.x`, then change it to:

```
except MySQLdb.Error:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Read [more](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#capturing-the-currently-raised-exception).

But according to your `print` statement, you write your script for `Python 2.x`, so it's better to run your code with `Python 2.x`, instead of `Python 3.x`

Also this `sys.path.append("../python2.7/site-packages")` line is strange in first line of your script.

Also your indention of your first code that you pasted was wrong, and i think your are still using that, please use current edited version that is now in your question.

Comment: I am still receiving the same error, I literally don't know what it means, I'm running it from CMD. Can you suggest anything else that could be the problem?

Comment: Have I forgotten to import something?

Comment: What's the output of this command? `python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"`?

Comment: 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Now save this line: `import sys;print(sys.version)` to a new file like `get_version.py` and then run it as you run your `pipelines.py` script, now what's the output of `get_version.py` script?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, I created a new file called get_version.py and ran: python get_version.py pipelines.py and got 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Your current code works (parsed) for `Python 2.7`, you can see your code parsed successfully [here](http://ideone.com/OIOSf3).

Comment: Exactly, this is what I do not understand, it does not like the word 'except' it gives me a syntax error every time.

Comment: You got error Like [this](http://ideone.com/I1mzNl) ? then you are still running your code with `Python 3.X`

Comment: No, I get an error like this.
    except MySQL.Error, e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the arrow pointing towards the except

Comment: Do you have `Python 3` on your system? your code is running with `Python 3` instead of running with `Python 2`.

Comment: I do not have python 3 installed

Comment: Ok !, I found your error, it's for your indention of your old code, looks at edited version and use it. i update my answer.